# Canvas Update Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I wrote a method to create a canvas

But I see that Canvas is not updated and the Gui elements are not updated

Please guide here as i want to implement the New Game functionality

Comment: Have you tried `self.canvas.destroy()`?

Comment: yes thanks it worked for me ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing all references to a Tkinter widget (like a `Canvas`) doesn't necessarily delete that object (or its child widgets) from a Tkinter application. You can test this with a small script:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
def f():
    tk.Label(root, text='hi').pack()

f()
```

No reference to that `Label` is ever saved, and it's local to a function scope anyway, and yet it persists. If you want to get rid of a Tkinter widget, use its `destroy` method.

```
self.canvas.destroy()
self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=2000, height=800)
...
```

Note that it's still good practice to keep references to your Tkinter objects so that you can work with them (like calling `destroy()` on them, for example), and some Tkinter objects actually are discarded when there are no more references to them, like image objects (e.g. as used by [`Canvas.create_image`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_image-method) and [`Label`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm#patterns)).